# Are there any "strategies" to tackling Binary Tree problems?

Tags: java, binary-tree, preorder

I hope this is an acceptable question. I understand the mode of thinking for recursion where I want to think of base case(s) then recursive cases but with some of the more difficult BST problems I just draw blanks and it feels like I get lost without having a good direction.

With linked-lists for example, it seems there's a pattern to approach a problem but BTs seem like either you know it or don't. Any tips/pointers? The only concept I've seem to have gotten down is that if I'm dealing with null nodes and I want to do something with them or about them, I'll have it as a case

```
if(root == null)
     //do something
```

or if I don't have anything to do with the null nodes then I use the inverted base case

```
if(root != null)
     //do stuff
else 
     //do nothing for null case
```

But even then I will come to a loss at what next. I guess here's an example of a problem I'm stuck with and don't know how to approach. I'm not necessarily looking for an answer, just a potential strategy to deal with questions like this (and regular binary tree questions).

---

Write a method `numberNodes` that changes the data stored in a binary tree, assigning sequential integers starting with 1 to each node so that a pre-order traversal will produce the numbers in order(1, 2, 3, etc.). For example, given the tree referenced by tree below at left, the call of `tree.numberNodes();` would overwrite the existing data assigning the nodes values from 1 to 6 so that a pre-order traversal of the tree would produce `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6`.

You are not to change the structure of the tree. You are simply changing the values stored in the data fields. Your method should return a count of how many nodes were in the tree.

Assume that you are adding this method to the `IntTree` class as defined below:

```
 public class IntTree {
     private IntTreeNode overallRoot;
     ...
 }
```

---

After staring at the code some more I figure I should be using my `int count` as a means to determine if I travel to the left root or right root since it's a binary search tree but I'm still unable to implement this functionality... ahh coding block!

Comment: Draw it out, write your Node class and walk through what you need to do

Answer (score 14):

When thinking about recursion with binary trees, the base case is an empty tree, so you're on the right track there. The other key conceptual element is to think in terms of the root, the left subtree, and the right subtree (either of which may be empty).

So I would break your sample problem down like this:

- If the tree is empty, there's nothing to do
- Otherwise, assign the next number to the root (Aha! - I need "the next number" to be passed in to this method.)
- Recurse on the left subtree, passing one more than the current number.
- Recurse on the right subtree, passing . . . Ah. I need to know what the next number is after the left subtree has been processed. Therefore, I need the call to the left subtree to return the next number (one more than the last number that was assigned). That means that I better do the same thing. That will be the number returned after recursing on the right subtree.
- When I call this method on the root node, it will return the next available number after setting all the values. The number of nodes that were set will be one less than this.
- Actually, it might be better to just return the last number used, rather than the next number available. Then I don't need a separate function just to subtract one from the result. So I'd better modify the previous analysis and say that the number to be passed into the method (as well as the number returned) should be the last number used (not the next available number) and adjust all the processing accordingly.

With that, you pretty much have the outline for the method. Here's how I would write it:

```
public class IntTree {
    private IntTreeNode overallRoot;

    public int numberNodes() {
        return numberNodes(overallRoot, 0);
    }

    /** Helper function */
    private static int numberNodes(IntTreeNode node, int n) {
        if (node != null) {
            node.data = ++n; // preorder means we assign to node first
            n = numberNodes(node.left, n);
            n = numberNodes(node.right, n);
        }
        return n;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the second numberNodes function have to be static? Would something break if it weren't static? I understand that static means it doesn't need a reference to the class, but is it still acceptable for it to have a reference to the tree class?

Comment: @randomUser47534 - In this case it doesn't have to be static, but there's no good reason for it to be an instance method, either. If it were called from a `static` context (e.g., another `static` method of `IntTree`) then making it an instance method would indeed break something. Also, if it were not `private`, then an instance method might be overridden by a subclass, leading to unexpected behavior; a `static` method (`private` or not) cannot be overridden (although it can be hidden).

Answer (score 3):

Generally - Draw it out, write your Node class and walk through what you need to do

In this case there are a few steps, you would need to essentially reverse engineer it.

1. figure out what is preorder traversal
2. draw out the tree and label each node with the correct number so that preorder would return what they need.
3. walk through what you need to do, easier to go with a 3 node tree and scale up.

E.g

> ```
>    1
>   / \ 
>  2   3
> ```

This is what you need

So you can see the rough idea is

```
Given X

  Set node.value = X
  X = Call on Left with X + 1    # add null check
  X = Call on Right with X + 1   # add null check
  return X
```

and your numberMethod() would be a wrapper which calls the above function on the root node with X =1, after checking for null root.

Comment: @MilanNovaković ah interesting, could you elabourate why it didnt work? Also you should add that to the question. 
p.s. root is a bad variable name here (or good?). And its a style choice, but I would move the null checks as I indicate above.

Comment: Sorry I'm having trouble commenting from the vehicle. I'll have to respond when I get to my destination so that I can properly format my answers.

Comment: @MilanNovaković dont bother formatting the code in the comment, easier if you add it to your question directly. Also don't type and drive :P

Comment: Well I lost what the code was for the answer I had previously but the reason it did not work was that it returned the wrong data values for each node. It worked properly going down the left but any deviance to the right contained wrong data fields. 

The answer Veronica Cornejo posted below did result in the right data fields but I had to make a slight adjustment in my public method to subtract one from "currentNumber" to get the proper value returned.

Comment: @MilanNovaković I can see the difference, but I think with the null checks in my way, this method would work also

Answer (score 2):

In first place, there are no null nodes.  What can be null are the `right` and `left` pointers/references.

In the second place, there are many different types of binary trees.  And I mean **essentially** different.  That's one reason why you don't see much commonality.

```
public class BTNode {
    int value;
    BTNode left;
    BTNode right;
}

public static int enumerate(BTNode startNode,int startNumber) {
    int currentNumber= startNumber ;
    if( startNode == null ) return currentNumber ;
    startNode.value= currentNumber ;    // also currentNumber++ and delete next instruction
    currentNumber++;
    currentNumber= enumerate(startNode.left,currentNumber) ;
    currentNumber= enumerate(startNode.right,currentNumber) ;    //  also together with return
    return currentNumber ;
}
```

The count has nothing to do with the values of the nodes.  It only has to do with their position.  Right or left is all that counts.

Comment: Why can't the root be null? How would you represent an empty tree?

Comment: When you say `root= null ;` you are assigning `null` to a variable that is not the root, it contains a reference to the root (if it existed).  Another way of viewing it:  Nodes are objects.  Objects **can not** be intrinsically null.  **References to objects** can be null.

Comment: And a third way if the previous 2 sounded too tied to a specific programming language:  A binary tree is a structure that consists of nodes.  Each node has a value, 0 or 1 left child, and 0 or 1 right child.  If a `null` node existed, you could access their left and right children.  Even set them to other nodes.  But then you would have a tree with a `null` root that is not empty.  Doesn't make any sense.

Comment: It seems overly pedantic to have a variable (field?) called `root` and not be able to say that it is "the root of the tree" and "the root may be null". Yes, all non-primitive variables in Java are references to objects and not objects, but the insisting on the distinction is awkward at best. Even the Java Language Specification style would be to describe `root` as being "of type `BTNode`" not "of type reference to `BTNode`".

Comment: Your solution did result in all the nodes having the proper data fields. I had arrived to a similar solution in my initial considerations of the problem except that instead of incrementing currentNumber on its own line I had passed currentNumber+1 in the recursive calls. Needless to say it failed spectacularly.

The only problem with your solution was that I had to subtract 1 from the returned value in the public method so that the count would be correct. Makes sense considering that currentNumber is incremented prior to the return call. Thank you!

Comment: @TedHopp  It seemed to me that those distinctions are critical for a person that probably is just learning Java (and maybe even programming).  Other than that, you are right.  I'm a pedantic!!! :-)

Comment: @MilanNovaković  Congratulations.  You would probably have come to it given a few more minutes.  Did you call `enumerate` with `startNumber=1`?  If yes, then that's correct.  You need to subtract 1 to obtain node count.  If not, I don't know what could have happened.

Answer (score 0):

Since I had not started out with java very well. For any person searching for a CPP implementation, I had tried and It worked in many test cases.

Here is my CPP implementation

```
struct Node{
      int data;
      Node* left, *right;
}
    
int NumberNodes(Node *root){
       
      if(root == NULL)
              return 0;
      
      if(root -> left != NULL)
              root -> left -> data = root -> data + 1;
      int l = NumberNodes(root -> left);

      if(root -> right != NULL)
              root -> right -> data = max(root->data, l) + 1;
      int r = NumberNodes(root -> right);

      return max(l, max(r, root->data));
}

int main(){
      Node *root = new Node();    //Or provide the root of your    ///  binary tree as mentioned in problem. 
      root->data = 1;
      int count = NumberNodes(root);  // count has the number of nodes in tree. 
}
```